# Find number of rows/columns in a GSL matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, gsl

Say I have some `gsl_matrix * A`. I want to write a function that retrieves e.g. the number of rows in this matrix, without having access to anything else besides the object A itself.

Example:

```
int num_rows(gsl_matrix * A){
    //some operation(s) on A that find the number of rows in the matrix
    //store that number in an int r
    return r;
}
```

What could I write to do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrices.html

`gsl_matrix` is defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t size1;
  size_t size2;
  size_t tda;
  double * data;
  gsl_block * block;
  int owner;
} gsl_matrix;
```

And

> The number of rows is size1. The range of valid row indices runs from 0 to size1-1. Similarly size2 is the number of columns. The range of valid column indices runs from 0 to size2-1. The physical row dimension tda, or trailing dimension, specifies the size of a row of the matrix as laid out in memory.

So if you want the number of rows in `A` then you would use:

```
int num_rows(gsl_matrix * A){
    int r = A->size1;
    return r;
}
```